# Why input() function in python gets only first written object?

Tags: python, input

For example:

```
a = input()
print(a)
```

Then, I am inputting those separated words written:
[separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSGxT.png)
In output, I am only getting "4"

But when I am inputting them like this:
[not separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cutqf.png)

I am getting each word.

How can I get each word by inputting separately?

Comment: Please provide your input/output both *as text* here, not as link to images. How exactly are you inputting line breaks in the first place?

Comment: Well, you can use either more inputs, which is not the best option or using different functions. What is your goal to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate `input()` for each line, so for 2 sentences you will need:

```
a = input()
b = input()
print(a)
print(b)
```

In case you are expecting multiple inputs, but you dont know how many you can place the `input()` inside a loop until an exit condition is met

```
line = ""
while line != "exit":
  line = input()
  # Do whatever with line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input()
```

reads just one line. To read all the lines, you need to use for example:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    <do sth>
```

if your variable is meant to be string, you can easily concatenate your strings with + .
If the variable should later be printed and give the same output as the given input, you can use '/n':

```
my_var = ""
for line in fileinput.input():
    my_var += '/n' + line
```